# DefaultTableCellRenderer and memory usage

Tags: java, swing, memory, tablecellrenderer

I did sort of emulation from androids expandableListView into swing. Recently i found that whenever the main frame is dragged (spinning), the application starts to consume an average of 1mb per spin. It decays overtime, but sometimes doesnt. Also occurs when the groups are called/closed.
I think the problem it´s the way that my DTCR was made.

```
setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new DefaultTableCellRenderer(){
        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected,
                boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
            super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
            System.out.println("One more time");
            setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            setForeground(Color.GRAY);
            setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 14));
            for(int i : groups_index){
                if(row == i){
                    setBackground(new Color(64,133,245));
                    setForeground(Color.WHITE);
                    setFont(new Font("Calibri", Font.BOLD, 18));
                    break;
                }
            }
            return this;
        }
    });
```

When the application starts, it always prints "One more time"x6 on console, when any group is called prints extra 7 lines and one extra line appears from nowhere by the time.

[printed lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ibev8.png)

I don´t really understand why it prints so many lines, which i think is the amound of cells that got render.

Comment: *"I don´t really understand why it prints so many lines,."* I don't really understand what your question is (because there is no question). What is your question?

Comment: 1. use value from for `value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column` instead of `(int i : groups_index){`, 2. setBackground(Color.WHITE); and             setForeground(Color.GRAY); should be directly called to the JTable.setWhatever

Comment: voting to close, because your question missing code in SSCCE / MCVE form

Comment: Maybe consider caching the `Font` instead of creating it each time

Comment: Font caching saved some memory thx. As i see the DTCR triggers whenever the frame is dragged, when mouse gets either pressed or released. Dont think i need to change anything else.